# Sublime Text line highlighter like Dreamweaver?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm used to using Dreamweaver but have recently tried moving to ST however I can't get over the way it highlights lines.

I'm used to the following:
[Dreamweaver Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvpQm.png)

Notice it highlights the whole line including blank areas. It also inverts the cursor when hovering over the line numbers.

ST does this however:
[Sublime Text Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0FWT.png)

Are there any plugins/ways to change this so I don't have to spend months getting used to a new thing?

Comment: I don't know of a plugin that will select-highlight line past the text in Sublime. It is interesting to note that WebStorm, PyCharm, IntelliJ and PhpStorm highlights the same way as Dreamweaver. Notepad++, Notepad, Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio highlight like Sublime.

Comment: The way Sublime does it seems preferable to me. If you have trailing whitespace, it will be a lot easier to tell.